# Maintain dynamically added controls and its values using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Good Morning,

I wrote a simple javascript to add `rows` into the `table`, then a label & checkbox in the row using `javascript` and I put a asp:button to postback the page. Now I need to display the data whatever I have added before postback(I click on the button). Can I have a piece of code what to write in code behind. Can anyone help.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Code I have wrote in a `input` type `button` to add:

```
var row = tblrw.insertRow(tblrw.rows.length);
rl = tblrw.rows.length;
var i = document.getElementById('txtAddItem').value;
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
var element2 = document.createElement("label");
element1.type = "checkbox";
element1.id = "chk" + i;
element1.className = "chkclass";
element2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
element2.className = "lblclass";
element2.id = "lbl" + i;
cell1.appendChild(element1);
cell2.appendChild(element2);
document.getElementById('txtAddItem').value = "";
```

Comment: where did you add the data! You said you have just dynamically added some HTML elements.

Comment: the code above is in a button click client event, I have put a button and a textbox in HTML tag, also an empty table to add the element dynamically,    Suppose If  add an Item in Text box then on clicking the button one row with 2 cells will add in the empty table. Now if I put another Server Button(asp:button) and if I set a post back event to that button then the page will postback. Now I want the added row again as it is in the page. Hope you might not understand this well.